# WAMP Server directing me to internet locations when I click on the folders in www folder

Tags: windows-8, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I installed WAMP Server on my laptop, which is running Windows 8 Pro.

I created a number of folders in the `www` folder in the `wamp` folder. My problem is that whenever I try accessing the folders from the localhost page in my web browser, I am taken to the internet page of the folder i.e. I have two folders named `family` & `prestashop`. Whenever I click on them, a tab opens in my browser directing me to `http://family/` instead of `http://localhost/family/`

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your `httpd.conf` (or `httpd-vhosts.conf`) it is hard to say where your problem is (or why it is a problem). Usually, to set up multiple sites, you will add virtual hosts to your `httpd.conf` or `httpd-vhosts.conf` which will tell WAMP what to do when people try to access that folder. The difference between a web address that looks like `http://localhost/family` and `http://family` is probably that you have set up a virtual host which allows you to get at that directory without running through 'localhost'.

Do you have something like this in your `http-vhosts.conf` in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache<version>\conf\extras\` ?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\wamp/www/family/"
  ServerName "family"
</VirtualHost>
```